# MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax dropping connection

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, mediatek

My MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax network card is dropping connection after moving from 6.2.0-21 to 6.3.0-7 official ubuntu kernel version. After selecting old kernel, everything works, but after selecting 6.3.0-7 my `plymounth` screen for disk decryption is showing in top left corner instead of the center and after booting up my wireless card is working for some period of time and then suddenly stops for 5s and then works again.

Except for ping stats in console, no information is shown in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog`.

My laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad L14

lspci

```
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.6 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013 E13 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
04:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
06:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev d1)
07:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
07:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
07:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
07:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
07:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
07:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
```

related dmesg

```
[  102.941974] mt7921e 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
[  112.526313] wlp6s0: authenticate with 6c:5a:b0:22:09:bf
[  113.032807] wlp6s0: send auth to 6c:5a:b0:22:09:bf (try 1/3)
[  113.147203] wlp6s0: authenticate with 6c:5a:b0:22:09:bf
[  113.156166] wlp6s0: send auth to 6c:5a:b0:22:09:bf (try 1/3)
[  113.318429] wlp6s0: authenticated
[  113.322871] wlp6s0: associate with 6c:5a:b0:22:09:bf (try 1/3)
[  113.332482] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 6c:5a:b0:22:09:bf (capab=0x1811 status=0 aid=5)
[  113.356952] wlp6s0: associated
[  113.593916] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp6s0: link becomes ready
```

As you can see, no information about dropping connection is shown.

I tried to disable power saving using `iw dev wlp6s0 set power_save off` but it didn't helped.

If this is necessary, I can bisect the kernel version to get to the root of the problem, but I would require a little assistance in doing so.

Additionally, I've seen that on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GamingLaptops/comments/pbbdcv/mediatek_mt7921_wifi_6_issues_used_in_most_2021/) users found some kind software issue with roaming in card one version down, but I am not sure how to disable roaming using `iw`.

EDIT 1:
My os is Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)
uname -a

```
Linux mkarol-ThinkPad-L14-Gen-3 6.3.0-7-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Apr 14 12:34:02 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

/etc/os-release

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu Mantic Minotaur (development branch)"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="23.10"
VERSION="23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)"
VERSION_CODENAME=mantic
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=mantic
LOGO=ubuntu-logo
```

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release detail; but the 6.3 kernel is *testing* only (and currently only available on *mantic*) so your details currently only match an off-topic *development* release, what are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 (mantic) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *mantic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 5 October 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 April 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)